# Datatables Single Column Filter

Tags: datatables

I read api doc and find individual column searching to filter data by column row, great but i just need add one dropdown filter by name on top (beside number filter)

[image]

Current setup (use tabletool and bootstrap)

```
$('table').DataTable({
    'aLengthMenu': [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, 'All']],
    'iDisplayLength': 25,
    'stateSave': true,
    'oLanguage': {
        'sLengthMenu': 'Show : _MENU_',
        'sSearch': 'Search : _INPUT_',
    },
    'oTableTools': {
        'sSwfPath': 'media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf'
    },
    /*
    'order': [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    'aoColumnDefs': [
                {
                    'bSortable': false,
                    'aTargets': [ -1, 0 ]
                }
            ]
    */
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Datatables Version 1.10 and upwards you want to use the [DOM](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option to position a div in the header where you want to add your filter and add your select to it.

```
 var table;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        table = $('#example').dataTable({
            "dom": "l<'#myFilter'>frtip"
        });
        var myFilter = '<select id="mySelect">'
          + '<option value="1">Searchval 1</option>'  
          + '<option value="2">Searchval 2</option>'
          + '<option value="3">Searchval 3</option>'
          + '</select>';
        $("#myFilter").html(myFilter);
        table.fnDraw();        
    });
```

Then add a [custom filter function](http://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html).

```
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data) { 
        //your filter stuff belongs here
        return true;
    });
```

And redraw the table everytime you change your filter.

```
    $("body").on("change", "#mySelect", function () {
        table.fnDraw();
    });
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q720zj6/4/) for an example of what more or less should fit your requirements.

Comment: This works great. But somehow, in my page, the mySelect dropdown appears on a new row below the Show [x] entries row. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That idea is implemented in [this](https://github.com/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter) DataTables plug-in, you may check out working **DEMO**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 //Source data definition 
 var tableData = [
    {item: 'banana', category: 'fruit', color: 'yellow'},
    {item: 'pear', category: 'fruit', color: 'green'},
    {item: 'cabbage', category: 'vegie', color: 'green'},
    {item: 'carrot', category: 'vegie', color: 'red'},
    {item: 'apple', category: 'fruit', color: 'red'},
    {item: 'kiwi', category: 'fruit', color: 'brown'}
 ];
 //DataTable definition 
 window.dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
   sDom: 'tF',
   data: tableData,
   columns: [{
     data: 'item',
     title: 'Item'
    }, {
     data: 'category',
     title: 'Category'
    }, {
     data: 'color',
     title: 'Color'
  
   }]
 });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/js/mfilter.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/css/mfilter.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting but your example probably doesn't work properly, there are no column filtering elements.

Comment: Click filter icon

Comment: There is no filter icon, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyJOf.png).

Comment: Which platform/OS/browser you're on?

Comment: There is a problem with SSL certificate for cdn.mfilter.cf, that is why the loading of your script fails. It works if I test your script locally.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue, because I failed to reproduce it. Hope you enjoy the plug-in. If so, stars on github are greatly appreciated.